# How to send JSON data from client to node.js server.

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

Here is **server.js**

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    mongoose = require( "mongoose" ),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/PvdEnroll', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
  }
});

var CheckBoxSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    npi: String,
    boxes:[ String]
});

var CheckBox = mongoose.model("CheckBox", CheckBoxSchema);
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

// here's where we get something from the client.
app.get("/checkbox.json", function (req, res) {
    CheckBox.find( {}, function(err, CheckBox) {
        console.log("STUBB2", checkbox);
        res.json(checkbox); 
    });
});

app.post("/checkbox", function (req, res) 
console.log("POSTING TO DB: ",req.body);

var newCkBoxData = new npiChecks({"npi": req.body.npi, "boxes":req.boxes});                 
    newCkBOxData.save(function(err, results) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("ERROR");
        } else {
            CheckBox.find({}, function(err, result) {
                if (err !== null) {
                    // the element dir not get saved
                    res.send("ERROR");
                }
                res.json(result);
            });
        }
    });                                                       
});
```

The client, **secA.js,** pertains to a single HTML page.

```
var main = function (checkBoxObjects) {
    "use strict";

    $.getJSON("../data/checkBoxesA.json", function(checkBoxTxt) {
        checkBoxTxt.forEach(function (data) {
            $(".checkbox-input").append("<input type='checkbox' unchecked/>");
            $(".checkbox-input").append(' ' + data.label + "<br/>");
            $(".checkbox-input").append(' ' + data.note +  "<br/>");
            $(".checkbox-input").append('              '+  "<br/>");
        });
   });
};
$(document).ready(main);

providerNPI_ckBs = [];
NPI_number = [];

var loopForm = function(form) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox')
            if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                providerNPI_ckBs += 1 + ' ';
            } else {
                providerNPI_ckBs += 0 + ' ';
            }
    }
    if (providerNPI_ckBs.length > 0) 
        if (NPI_number.length > 0) 
           createJSONobj(); 
}

var getNPI = function() {
    NPI_number = document.getElementById("text_field1").value;
        if (NPI_number.length > 0)
            if (providerNPI_ckBs.length > 0) {
               createJSONobj(); 
            }
}

var createJSONobj = function() {
    var JSONobj = '{' + JSON.stringify(NPI_number) + ':' + 
                   JSON.stringify(providerNPI_ckBs) + '}';
    JSON.stringify(JSONobj);
    console.log(JSONobj);

    // here we'll do a quick post to our todos route
    $.post("npi_checks", JSONobj, function (response) {
        console.log("We posted and the server responded!");
        console.log(response);
    });
}

// Note: This is temporary as I'm only intending to sent JSON data one way
// to the server. I'd just like to verify that I can send data both ways
$(document).ready(function (checkBoxObjects) {
    $.getJSON("checkbox.json", function (checkBoxObjects) {
        console.log("Client Recieved Array from Server: ", checkBoxObjects);
        main(checkBoxObjects);
    });
});
```

The Chrome console responds immediately with GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/html/checkbox.json 404 (Not Found)

The page loads and will accept data which the **secA.js** script formats as JSON. The database has been started by the server. All I need to know is how to send the data over to the server!

I'm clearly new to javascript and producing this application is part of learning the language along with MongoDB. I've structured this application similarly to an example tutorial book. One difference is that in the tutorial the traffic is two ways between client and server.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try the url  `http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkbox.json`

Comment: This produced: GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkbox.json net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE   Also, the "npi_checks" is an historical relic was changed to "checkbox"

Comment: The trick seem to be in determining the first argument for .getJSON() and .post()

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the missing `{` after `app.post("/checkbox", function (req, res)`?

Comment: Oh! The curley bracket is actually there but did't get pasted by accident!

Answer (score 0):

If the first argument to *post*, on the client side, is changed from ""npi_checks"  to "/checkbox"  to match the first argument *app.post* the data gets to the server and is loaded into mongoldb. This is the simple solution.